# wordpress htaccess rewrite rule https to http

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

we have a problem with our site, if i write https://example.com it goes to a different website, beacuse we are on the same IP with other domains. How can i redirect it to my http:// domain?
here is my htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} =on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

 # BEGIN WordPress
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force https
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Important**: don't forget to change yourdomain.com to real domain.

Comment: Thanks Nerijus, It gives too much redirects, but i think it is the host problem, (some hidden htaccess). So thank you very much for your help!!!